# subquery mysql to get realted data from three tables

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am fetching related data from 3 tables.

table `useracc` has users account transactions with order id in `details` column. This is basic table on which query to find 'gift%' in `details` column runs...

```
"SELECT * FROM `useracc` WHERE `details` LIKE 'gift%' ORDER BY `id` DESC"
```

Now i want to fetch the Order id from these results in `details` column which is given as 'gift order id:245'. i want this 245 and run another query to look for 245 in 2nd table i.e. `transaction`. 
i want to fetch column `senderemail` in table `transaction` where column `orderid` is 245. suppose this returns abc@abc.com

now in third table i.e. `users` i want to find the username related to that email.
i want to run query to fetch column `username` in table `users` where `useremail` is abc@abc.com.

this username is to be displayed in every row of table format containing the results of our first query

how can i do this using subquery. please help

Comment: Why a subquery instead of a join?

Comment: i can use join too. can you help with an example? thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT u.username, ua.*
FROM useracc AS ua
JOIN transaction AS t ON ua.details = CONCAT('gift order id:', t.id)
JOIN users AS u ON u.useremail = t.senderemail
WHERE ua.details LIKE 'gift order id:%'
ORDER BY ua.id DESC
```

The `WHERE` clause isn't strictly necessary, since it's redundant with the `ON` condition. But it might speed up the query -- try it with and without and see which is faster.

Comment: Use the username completion after `@` so you spell the name right.